# Can't install firefox extension via HKEY_CURRENT_USER

Tags: firefox-addon, registry

According to the documentation provided [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Adding_Extensions_using_the_Windows_Registry) it says I should be able to install an extension through HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wow6432Node\Mozilla\Firefox\Extensions but whenever I add it there, Firefox does not find it. But, the thing is if I add the same key under the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE location, Firefox finds the extension just fine!

I am a little confused to why and how this could happen.

Edit: Installing on a Windows 7 64 bit version.

Answer (score 1):

No, the correct registry key is `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mozilla\Firefox\Extensions` - both on x86 and x64 Windows. The reason is that the `Software` key [is only redirected for HKLM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384253%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software` however is shared between 32-bit and 64-bit applications.

If adding your extension to this key shows no effect, you might want to check the value of the [`extensions.enabledScopes` preference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Installing_extensions#Disabling_install_locations) (you can see and change it under `about:config`). E.g. if its value is 5 then it allows only extensions in user's profile (value 1) and the ones provided by Firefox (value 4). You have to make sure that the combination also includes the value 2.